# Why the error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." appears, when there are no async actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I was trying to figure out React deeper and stuck on this error. 
It didn't allow me to dispatch any actions. However, I'm not using async at all. 
[Here you can find codesandbox of the full app.](https://codesandbox.io/s/buyrnm-wn6xk)

I've added `thunkMiddleware` to the store, so the app will work. 
However I can't understand what is going on?

Here are the action creators, inside which I cloudn't dispatch. 
I've searched for different similar answers, and all those were connected to incorrect usage of 
async actions. Mine are sync:

```
import CART_ACTIONS from "../action_types/cartActionTypes";

function addToCart(item) {
  return dispatch => dispatch({ type: CART_ACTIONS.ADD_ITEM, item: item });
}

function removeFromCart(item) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: CART_ACTIONS.REMOVE_ITEM, item });
  };
}

function clearCart(item) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: CART_ACTIONS.CLEAR_CART });
  };
}

export const cartActions = { addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart };
```

Comment: What should I do to replicate the issue on the sandbox?

Comment: Remove applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware). I've updated the link. You can open the sandbox console(under the app view, left bottom corner), there you'll see an error.

Comment: Why do you remove applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware) if it works with it?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, that is a great question :D. 
However I'm not using any async calls and want to know, why is this happening at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your cartActions like this, if you don't want to use thunkMiddleware:

```
import CART_ACTIONS from "../action_types/cartActionTypes";

function addToCart(item) {
   return({ type: CART_ACTIONS.ADD_ITEM, item: item });
}

function removeFromCart(item) {
    return({ type: CART_ACTIONS.REMOVE_ITEM, item });

}

function clearCart(item) {
    return({ type: CART_ACTIONS.CLEAR_CART });
}

export const cartActions = { addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart };
```

Simply, you just need to return an action which must be an object with type property and optionally a payload.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/buyrnm-e5f7i)

Comment: So I don't have to use dispatch for that? I mean dispatch({ type: CART_ACTIONS.CLEAR_CART }). 
What you are saying is, this object is passed to dispatch?

Comment: @Animus you shouldn’t use dispatch if you don’t have async action. Returning a simple object as I showed in the answer is one of the fundamentals of redux.

Comment: @Animus you are welcome, I would appreciate if you can upvote.